# How to disable layout and view renderer in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

How can i disable layout and view renderer in Zend Framework 2.x? I read documentation and can't get any answers looking in google i found answer to Zend 1.x and it's

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

But it's not working any more in Zend Framework 2.x. I need to disable both view renderer and layout for Ajax requests.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just use `setTerminal(true)` in your controller to disable layout.

This behaviour documented here: [Zend View Quick Start :: Dealing With Layouts](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#dealing-with-layouts)

Example:

```
<?php
namespace YourApp\Controller;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class FooController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function fooAction()
    {
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setVariables(array('key' => 'value'))
              ->setTerminal(true);

    return $viewModel;
    }
}
```

If you want to send JSON response instead of rendering a .phtml file, try to use JsonRenderer:

Add this line to the top of the class:

```
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
```

and here an action example which returns JSON:

```
public function jsonAction()
{
    $data = ['Foo' => 'Bar', 'Baz' => 'Test'];
    return new JsonModel($data);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Don't forget to add `ViewJsonStrategy` to your `module.config.php` file to allow  controllers to return JSON. Thanks @Remi!

```
'view_manager' => [
    'strategies' => [
        'ViewJsonStrategy'
    ],
],
```

Comment: Don't forget to add this 'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ), to you config.php from http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/returning-json-from-a-zf2-controller-action/

Comment: if we want to return viewModel  with json encoding what should we do ?

Answer (score 4):

You can add this to the end of your action:

```
return $this->getResponse();
```

Answer (score 4):

Slightly more info on the above answer... I use this often when outputting different types of files dynamically: json, xml, pdf, etc... This is the example of outputting an XML file.

```
// In the controller
$r = $this->getResponse();

$r->setContent(file_get_contents($filePath)); //

$r->getHeaders()->addHeaders(
    array('Content-Type'=>'application/xml; charset=utf-8'));

return $r;
```

The view is not rendered, and only the specified content and headers are sent.