# How to render a view in modal window using ajax in ZF2?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

I try to render an action with a dedicated view in a modal window with an ajax call in Zend Framework 2.

This is my controller action :

```
public function myAction()
{
    $htmlViewPart = new ViewModel();
    $htmlViewPart->setTemplate('path/to/my/view')
                 ->setTerminal(true)
                 ->setVariables(['arrayVar' => ['a', 'b', 'c']]);

    return $htmlViewPart;
}
```

The view :

```
<?php
    foreach($arrayVar as $k => $v)
    {
        echo $k . ':' . $v . '<br>';
    }
```

The js :

```
$(".my-modal-link").click(function() {
    $('#myModal .modal-body').load($(this).data('/url/to/my/action'));
});
```

This not do the trick. I also tried with a JSON model too:

```
public function myAction()
{
    $htmlViewPart = new ViewModel();
    $htmlViewPart->setTemplate('path/to/my/view')
                 ->setTerminal(true)
                 ->setVariables(['arrayVar' => ['a', 'b', 'c']]);

    $htmlOutput = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewrenderer')->render($htmlViewPart);

    $jsonModel = new JsonModel();
    $jsonModel->setVariables(['html' => $htmlOutput]);

    return $jsonModel;
}
```

But the final render in the modal is something like :

```
{"html":"0:a\u003Cbr\u003E1:b\u003Cbr\u003E2:c\u003Cbr\u003E"}
```

Have an idea to how achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

Just create an empty layout returning content.

```
// Application/view/layout/ajax.phtml
<?php

echo $this->content;
```

And set this template in the action view

```
<?php

$this->layout()->setTemplate('layout/ajax');
```

It works now with Jquery $.load() / ViewModel strategy

Answer (score 1):

All you need is disabling the layout using `setTerminal()` and returning proper model from your controller to render HTML output in your modal.

In your case, you have to return a **ViewModel** instance. So, your first approach is correct. This should work:

```
$htmlViewPart = new ViewModel();
$htmlViewPart->setTemplate('path/to/my/view')
             ->setTerminal(true)
             ->setVariables(['arrayVar' => ['a', 'b', 'c']]);

return $htmlViewPart;
```

The second case is; you're trying to use a HTML output as json data. Try to change your ajax loading mechanism similar to this:

```
$(".my-modal-link").click(function() {
    $.get("/url/to/my/action", function(data) {
        $('#myModal .modal-body').html(data);
    });
});
```

This will be append the rendered output (which doesnt have a layout) into modal's body. You may also want to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18015818/199593) for **JsonModel** scenario.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ty for your response foozy. I want to use the first case, with an instance of ViewModel. This is the most logic approach. The call is working but all the layout is loaded in the modal window ...

Comment: Interesting. What happens when you call /url/to/my/action from your browser?

Comment: The layout is displayed. And if I comment `setTerminal(true)`, the view and its content are displayed too

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem this works...

```
$.get("<?php echo $this->url('your url'); ?>", function(data) 
{
    console.log(data);
    $('#myModal .modal-body').html(data);
});
```